# C# interpreter add-in for visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, add-in, interpreter

I come from a lisp background where I could type in snippets to the command line while coding, to make sure I get a small chunk of code correct the first time.  Its great for testing string formatting, simple math calls, etc without having to recompile a whole project to test small changes.

Is there a feature or add-in in visual studio 2010 to get this type of functionality, say like a watch window that runs when you aren't actually executing the program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can abuse the Intermediate window to evaluate things (in debug mode). However, i'd suggest **LinqPad** it has basic code execution on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

As well as [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) mentioned by Aren, you might want to look at Mono's [CsharpRepl](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl).

I don't know if either of these have Visual Studio add-ins available, but it's an interesting thought...

Answer (score 2):

I usually use LinqPad, but have you tried the [immediate window?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy(VS.10).aspx)  Personally, this kind of thing is great for creating a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

One other you should check out is [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/)